# Unity 5 keeps giving me errors

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

since I've downloaded Unity 5. I have encountered countless errors. All are alike so I googled it. I found a common answer but I don't know what they mean by it.

**errors:**

> Assets/6by7/ProGrids/Scripts/Editor/ProGrids_Base.js(5,42): BCE0144: 'UnityEngine.Resources.LoadAssetAtPath(String, System.Type)' is obsolete. Use AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath instead (UnityUpgradable)
>
> Assets/6by7/ProGrids/Scripts/Editor/ProGrids_Base.js(6,40): BCE0144: 'UnityEngine.Resources.LoadAssetAtPath(String, System.Type)' is obsolete. Use AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath instead (UnityUpgradable)
>
> Assets/6by7/ProGrids/Scripts/Editor/ProGrids_Base.js(7,41): BCE0144: 'UnityEngine.Resources.LoadAssetAtPath(String, System.Type)' is obsolete. Use AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath instead (UnityUpgradable)
>
> Assets/6by7/ProGrids/Scripts/Editor/ProGrids_Base.js(8,46): BCE0144: 'UnityEngine.Resources.LoadAssetAtPath(String, System.Type)' is obsolete. Use AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath instead (UnityUpgradable)

**This is the common answer:**
It basically tells you what to do, instead of `blahblah.renderer` you now need to do, `blahblah.GetComponent(Renderer)`. It looks a little more work, but it is more generalised for all components now, and more obvious what the code used to do in the background.

I don't know what it's telling me to do.

Comment: I don't quite understand because it seems that the error just says what you need to do : "Use AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath instead (UnityUpgradable)". So what's the problem ? Just put AssetDatabase.blablabla instead of UnityEngine.blablabla

Comment: You googled it, did you even bother understanding the error? Good luck on big projects using JS by the way.

Comment: Hi @ChanelNo5.  Welcome to the site - you must "TICK" the useful answer below, to keep the site tidy, and so that you get points so you can ask more questions.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you need to drop "javascript".  It's not realistically possible to use it for Unity these days - indeed Unity are dropping it soon. c# is actually easier to learn and use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's telling you exactly what you already said.
You should write and use

```
blahblah.GetComponent<Renderer>()
```

instead of

```
blahblah.renderer
```

You should check out [UNITY 5: API CHANGES](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/23/unity5-api-changes-automatic-script-updating/) and [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/getcomponent).

Comment: As Claudio explains, this is a COMMON PROBLEM if you take an old Unity project, and open it in Unity today.  It is easy to fix, as he has explained.